# PHP if num_rows is not empty insert data else update the information

Tags: php, mysqli

I got this if statement that executes this function

if table is not empty update the required information else execute the insert query. but the problem is i cannot get into the insert part instead I'm being returned to the update query even though the table is empty.

Below is my query which checks if the information is already in the table.

```
$checkquery = "SELECT user_type_id , user_school_verification_id , resource_no ,resource_title , SUM(quantity) as Total_Quantity FROM tbl_borrow_issuance WHERE user_type_id = ? AND user_school_verification_id = ? AND resource_no = ?";
    $stmt1 = $mysqlconnection->prepare($checkquery);
    $stmt1->bind_param("sss",$getusertype, $getstudentno , $getresourceno );
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->store_result();
    $stmt1->bind_result($user_type_id, $user_school_verification_id, $resource_no, $resource_title, $Total_Quantity );
```

And Here is my if statement

```
if($stmt1->num_rows > 0){

    while ($stmt2->fetch())
    {
        $user_type_id = $user_type_id;
        $borrow_count = $borrow_count;  
        $Total_Quantity = $Total_Quantity;
        $resource_no = $resource_no;
        // $gettotalfinal = $getresourcequantity + 

        if ($getusertype == $user_type_id && $getresourcequantity <= $borrow_count)
        {
            if ($getusertype == $user_type_id && $Total_Quantity == $borrow_count){

                echo "ERRORMAX";

            }
            else
            {
                $add_quantity = "UPDATE tbl_borrow_issuance SET quantity = quantity + ? WHERE resource_no = ? ";
                $stmt3 = $mysqlconnection->prepare($add_quantity);
                $stmt3->bind_param("ss", $getresourcequantity, $resource_no);
                if ($stmt3->execute()) {
                    echo "SUCCESS";
                }else
                {
                echo "ERROR";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
        echo "ERRORUSER";
        }
    }   
}
else
{
        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_borrow_issuance (user_type_id , user_school_verification_id, resource_no , resource_title , quantity ) VALUES (? , ? , ? ,? , ?)";
        $stmt = $mysqlconnection->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss",$getusertype, $getstudentno, $getresourceno , $getresourcetitle ,$getresourcequantity);
        if ($stmt->execute()) 
        {

            echo "SUCCESS1";
        }
        else
        {

            echo "ERROR";
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested the query directly on the database, with the same parameters that are going to the script? It is not returning nothing?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Where is it stuck? Even with some simple `var_dump`s, you might be able to figure that out

Comment: Yup i have tested the query and it returns data @DioneiMiodutzki

Comment: @NicoHaase it echoes the "SUCCESS" in inspect tool in chrome

Comment: So, you've tried debugging yet? What does `$stmt1->num_rows` contain?

Comment: @NicoHaase the table is empty but it returns the "SUCCESS" and not the insert query

Comment: Please answer the questions if you seek help. If "SUCCESS" is printed, then the update query fired. If your table was empty before, updating does.... nothing.

Comment: Yes , i tried inserting dummy data to my table and execute the code the update query works , the only problem is the insert part.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a aggreation query when you use SUM on your query. Long story short, this query will always return 1 row, no mather what the table have.

You want to check the Total Quantity, not the row number.

So changing the if to:

```
if($Total_Quantity > 0){
```

Should do the trick.